# Output to console list of all li in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a task to create a code to list of children elements of div, list all li tags in div with class "sample_class_2" and also output to console text from li tags. My code in current state looks like this:

```
var divListChildren = $('div.sample_clas_2').find('li').text();
console.log(divListChildren);
```

But it lists only first element, not all of them. What did i do wrong in here? I am supposed to do this with jquery or with js or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var divListChildren = "";

    $("div.sample_clas_2").find("li").each(function(index,ele){
        divListChildren += ele.innerHTML + " ";
    })

    console.log(divListChildren);
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sample_clas_2">
            <li>Ehsan</li>
            <li>taghdisi</li>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               var divListChildren = "";
                $("div.sample_clas_2").find("li").each(function(index,ele){
                  divListChildren += ele.innerHTML + " ";
               })
                console.log(divListChildren);
           })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```
var childrenList = [];
var sampleClass = $('.sample_clas_2');
sampleClass.find('li').each(function(i, v){
  childrenList.push($(v).text());
});
console.log(childrenList);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sample_clas_2">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y2pa13tc/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.sample_clas_2').find('li').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```